# Why is Python erasing all data in my text file?

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding what's going on. I have just been introduced to the open() and close() commands in Python. I have a code that is very similar to the code below:

```
def function1(s): #creates a text file with the name s
   file = open(s + ".txt", "w+")
   file.writelines(['1\n', '2\n', '3\n'])
```

Running this code works just fine. In this case, Python will create a text file with 4 lines. The first three lines are 1, 2, 3 respectively, and the last line is empty (this is the outcome I want).

My problem begins when I try to open this file and operate with its values. I have a second code which looks like this:

```
def function2():
   filename = input("Enter the file name here: ")
   file = open(filename + ".txt", "w+")
   contents = []
   for i in file:
      contents.append(i)
   print(contents)
```

Suppose I call `function1("test")`. Then test.txt is created and works fine. But then, when I call `function2()` and enter `test` as the user input, Python will print `[]` and I find that the contents of test.txt have been erased! What is happening here?

Note: not sure if this matters, but I have tried changing the body of `function2()` to have `file = open(filename + ".txt", "r")` instead, with no success.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for i in file.readlines()`? Also debugging is off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that (new here). `file.readlines()` seemed to work. Thank you!

Comment: Check the [tour](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour).